# How may I build a logical hierarchical tree using a flat xml as input..?

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<root>
    <food>
        <id>fruits</id>
        <parent />
        <level>1</level>
    </food>
    <food>
        <id>sourFruits</id>
        <parent>fruits</parent>
        <level>2</level>
    </food>
    <food>
        <id>sweetFruits</id>
        <parent>fruits</parent>
        <level>2</level>
    </food>
    <food>
        <id>lemon</id>
        <parent>sourFruits</parent>
        <level>3</level>
    </food>
    <food>
        <id>grapes</id>
        <parent>sweetFruits</parent>
        <level>3</level>
    </food>
    <food>
        <id>oranges</id>
        <parent>sweetFruits</parent>
        <level>3</level>
    </food>
</root>
```

The level tag denotes the hierarchy(node level of the logical tree to form).
I need to transform this xml(above) to another xml like below.
The picture is like :- 
fruits is the root element.
fruits has two childs sourFruits and sweetFruits.
sourFruits has a child lemon and sweetFruits has oranges and grapes as children.

Am really confused at this point...

```
<goodFoods>
    <foodType>
        <name>fruits</name>
        <taste>
            <tasteType>sourFruits</tasteType>
            <fruit>
                <fruitname>lemon</fruitname>
            </fruit>
        </taste>
        <taste>
            <tasteType>sweetFruits</tasteType>
            <fruit>
                <fruitname>grapes</fruitname>
            </fruit>
            <fruit>
                <fruitname>oranges</fruitname>
            </fruit>
        </taste>
    </foodType>
</goodFoods>
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: The taste tags are repeating with faulty children..

Comment: no, I mean what's the XSLT you've got so far

Comment: Your input XML contains enough information to form a hierarchy, but it does not contain information about what the different levels of the hierarchy represent.  In particular, it doesn't indicate that the second level is a categorization by flavor, or that third is individual fruits.  To produce that, then, you need to build it into the transform.

Comment: Also, as long as all the `<id>`s in the input are distinct, the `<level>` elements are redundant.  You can use them for your purposes, but you don't need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You want to reference `foot` elements by their `level` and by their parent, with XSLT you can do this using a key, in XSLT 3.0 a composite key

```
<xsl:key name="children" match="food" composite="yes" use="xs:integer(level), string(parent)"/>
```

is fine, with earlier versions of XSLT you would need to use a single key value like a string that concatenates the level and parent with e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="children" match="food" use="concat(level, '|', parent)"/>
```

Then it is just necessary to transform each level to the target format and find the children with the key so with XSLT 3.0 you would have

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <goodFoods>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', (1, ''))"/>
    </goodFoods>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="food[level = 1]">
    <foodType>
        <name>{id}</name>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', (level + 1, string(id)))"/>
    </foodType>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="food[level = 2]">
    <taste>
        <tasteType>{id}</tasteType>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', (level + 1, string(id)))"/>
    </taste>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="food[level = 3]">
    <fruit>
        <fruitName>{id}</fruitName>
    </fruit>
</xsl:template>
```

The complete stylesheet with XSLT 3 is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:key name="children" match="food" composite="yes" use="xs:integer(level), string(parent)"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <goodFoods>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', (1, ''))"/>
        </goodFoods>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="food[level = 1]">
        <foodType>
            <name>{id}</name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', (level + 1, string(id)))"/>
        </foodType>     
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="food[level = 2]">
        <taste>
            <tasteType>{id}</tasteType>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', (level + 1, string(id)))"/>
        </taste>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="food[level = 3]">
        <fruit>
            <fruitName>{id}</fruitName>
        </fruit>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the XSLT 1 or 2 key you would need to adjust the templates slightly with e.g.

```
    <xsl:template match="food[level = 1]">
        <foodType>
            <name>
               <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
            </name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', concat(level + 1, '|', id))"/>
        </foodType>     
    </xsl:template>
```

It should be clear from that how to adjust the other templates.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about XSLT, but here's how to do it in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh):

```
open file.xml ;
for &{ sort :n :d :k level /root/food[parent!=""] } {
    my $f = . ;
    mv $f into ../food[id=$f/parent] ;
}

rename goodFoods /root ;

rename fruit    //food[level = 3] ;
rename taste    //food[level = 2] ;
rename foodType //food[level = 1] ;

rename fruitname //fruit/id ;
rename tasteType //taste/id ;
rename name      //foodType/id ;

remove ( //level | //parent ) ;

save :b ;
```

After processing with `xmllint --format`, the output is

```
<goodFoods>
  <foodType>
    <name>fruits</name>
    <taste>
      <tasteType>sourFruits</tasteType>
      <fruit>
        <fruitname>lemon</fruitname>
      </fruit>
    </taste>
    <taste>
      <tasteType>sweetFruits</tasteType>
      <fruit>
        <fruitname>grapes</fruitname>
      </fruit>
      <fruit>
        <fruitname>oranges</fruitname>
      </fruit>
    </taste>
  </foodType>
</goodFoods>
```